# Looking for the full path to Kate on Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, editor, filezilla

I need to set Kate as editor for various filetypes in FileZilla.
FileZilla wants the path to my 'custom editor' (Kate).
But I can't seem to locate Kate!

Can anyone assist? TIA!

**edit: found... /usr/bin/kate

the trick was setting it as custom editor before trying to add mime types...

Comment: You could use `type -p kate`.

Comment: @waltinator, never thought to do this: I'd always used `which` (e.g., `which kate`). Nice.